# Redesign Issue (Multiple Inheritance without Multiple Inheritance)

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am currently working on a game engine for work and have hit a wall on my idea. I have multiple objects (called prefabs) that have very common properties such as `Position`, `Rotation`, and `Scale`. There are more, but let's just focus on those for this particular issue.

The idea was to create a base class called `RenderObject` in which these properties will live; however, there's an issue. Some objects in our engine can be rendered both in `3D` and in `2D`. I want to have a singular `Render` method for each object that handles both cases. Now, this was simple to solve as I can just create two virtual methods:

```
public virtual void Render() { }
public virtual void Render(CameraMode mode) { }
```

This makes it easy to render the objects the right way. Say for example I have a collection of `2D` only objects; I can simply call `Render` for these objects and their `2D` render code is executed. If I have a collection of objects that can be rendered in `2D` or `3D` mode then I just call `Render(CameraMode)` instead.

The issue lies with the properties; with `DirectX 11` most `2D` specific methods (such as `DrawLine`) require `Vector2` objects for the positions. This is an issue for simplification if the base class only has `Vector3` objects for the positions. I then have to grab the `X` and `Y` properties of the `Vector3` and create a new `Vector2` object every draw call. Instead, I went with the idea of creating a secondary base class called `RenderObject2D` that hides the `Vector3` by returning a `Vector2` instead. However, this is still an issue as this doesn't cover objects that can be rendered in `2D` and `3D`. I can implement the multiple `Render` method option and just render differently for the object, but then I have `2D` objects that have unused `3D` fields and properties such as the `Buffer` objects that aren't used in `2D`.

---

### Code Example

The current code isn't the route I want to go as I'm not a fan of hiding underlying properties. Typically you add to a base class, not take away.

```
// Currently 3D is perspective and 2D is orthographic.
public enum CameraMode { Perspective, Orthographic }
public class RenderObject {
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; } = Vector3.Zero;
    public virtual void Render() { }
    public virtual void Render(CameraMode mode) { }
    ...
}
public class RenderObject2D : RenderObject {
    public new Vector2 Position {
        get { return new Vector2(base.Position.X, base.Position.Y); }
        set { base.Position = new Vector3(value, 0); }
    }
}
public class Tree : RenderObject2D {
    // Can be rendered in 2D as a sprite and 3D as a model.
    // Current structure does not support this.
}
```

---

Is there a smarter way to accomplish this in a simplistic manner or am I stuck implementing the two different methods and just deal with the trade-off?

Comment: You could turn RenderObject into an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the *type* of a property in a derived class is going to be a maintenance headache.  It's very confusing.

You also haven't saved yourself from creating Vector2d objects.  Every time you retrieve RenderObject2d.Position, you're instantiating a Vector2d.

I would just do this:

```
public class RenderObject {
    public Vector3 Position3d 
    { 
        get => _position3d; 
        set
        {
            _position3d = value;  
            Position2d = new Vector2(_position3d.X, _position3d.Y);
        } 
    };
    private Vector3 _position3d;

    public Vector2 Position2d { get; private set; }

    public virtual void Render() { }
    public virtual void Render(CameraMode mode) { }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is what I initially thought of doing, but wanted to avoid having multiple properties for different dimensions. I'm looking over documentation for other popular engines to see if I can find a consensus amongst them. So far it seems like most are focused on 3D and require the user to convert to 2D.

Comment: Having multiple properties for 2d vs 3d is better than having multiple *classes* for it.